# PHP form -- check if file was attached

Tags: php, forms, validation, contact-form

I have a php contact form that currently validates an attachment for file type and file size, *but* I also need it to check if the user forgot to attach an image altogether (ie, photo attachment should be a "required field" and throw an 'please attach photo' message if so).

Form in question:

http://www.cucinadellanonna.com/nominate-form.php

This is the part of the code that checks the attachment... I've tried adding a few things, to no avail, so I'm just stabbing in the dark.

```
//file upload validation


     if(!empty($this->fileupload_fields))
    {
     if(!$this->ValidateFileUploads())
     {
        $ret = false;
     }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes)
{
    $ret=true;
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
    $extn = $info['extension'];
    $extn = strtolower($extn);

    $arr_valid_filetypes= explode(',',$valid_filetypes);
    if(!in_array($extn,$arr_valid_filetypes))
    {
        $this->add_error("Valid file types are: $valid_filetypes");
        $ret=false;
    }
    return $ret;
}

function ValidateFileSize($field_name,$max_size)
{
    $size_of_uploaded_file = 
            $_FILES[$field_name]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs
    if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_size)
    {
        $this->add_error("The file is too big. File size should be less than $max_size KB");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
{
    if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function ValidateFileUploads()
{
    $ret=true;
    foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
    {
        $field_name = $upld_field["name"];

        $valid_filetypes = $upld_field["file_types"];

        if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if($_FILES[$field_name]["error"] != 0)
        {
            $this->add_error("Error in file upload; Error code:".$_FILES[$field_name]["error"]);
            $ret=false;
        }

        if(!empty($valid_filetypes) &&
         !$this->ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes))
        {
            $ret=false;
        }

        if(!empty($upld_field["maxsize"]) &&
        $upld_field["maxsize"]>0)
        {
            if(!$this->ValidateFileSize($field_name,$upld_field["maxsize"]))
            {
                $ret=false;
            }
        }

    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If no files have been uploaded the following statement will return 0:

```
count($_FILES);
```

You could use that in an if statement to determine if there are files being held in preparation for moving and renaming.

```
function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
{
    if(count($_FILES) > 0)
    {
        if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am embarrassed to admit I don't have enough php chops to form the statement... I've tried reverse engineering a bunch of the other statements but I'm just stabbing in the dark.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it includes a modification to your function.

Comment: Where in that statement would I put the `$this->add_error` error message?

Comment: I figured you would know that, you wrote this code didn't you?

Comment: No, it's a free* form I grabbed and reverse engineered (*fully free license, both non-commercial and commercially).

Comment: well, your best bet is to get a bit more php knowledge behind you, the web has no shortage of tutorials for... everything.  once you have a better understanding on the concepts and techniques, you will find this sort of thing you are trying to do very easy.

Comment: Despite my knowledge deficit in php, I'm actually pretty skilled in other areas. I have spent two days querying and have found many solutions, none of which has worked for me. Most statements deal with inspecting attributes of the file and throwing errors AFTER the file has been uploaded. I need to detect if a file was ever selected in the first place.

I'd be happy to PayPal you a few bucks to help me solve this.